# How to skip configurable form & its actions in Install4j

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4J v6.0.3.
There are 2 doubts i wants to clear.

1) Is there a way to skip configurable form & its action directly using skip button in footer bar of each? I don't wants to ask user whether he/she wants to skip next action or not. Is there a way to get skip button on form footer itself along with next, cancel etc.

2) Is there a way to edit or change the default content of Welcome & Finish screen in install4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As this is not possible add skip button in footer of configurable form (As per @Ingo Kegel).

Got answer for 2nd question.

We can edit each message we see in installer screen using message_en.utf8 file. we can override messages in this file & specify this file under 'Language' section.

Answer (score 1):

While there is currently no way to add a "Skip" button at the bottom, you can add a "Button" form component to the configurable form and call

```
context.goForward(1, true, false);
```

in its "Action script" property.

The second "false" parameter indicates that the actions attached to the current screen should not be executed.

As to your second question (please ask a separate question in the future), you can add "Configurable banner" forms instead of the standard screens.